# From a CSS perspective, what state is an input button in when you click, hold down for a second and then drag away?

Tags: html, css

[image: Unknown CSS button state]

Above you have a button in 3 states, normal, hover, and then what is the third state called? What would need to put into my CSS to style this?

The button seems to be in this state after a right click too.

Really simple probably, I know, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Normal --> Hover --> Active (still pink) --> Focused (not pink anymore)

Comment: `btn:focus` did it, maybe you should answer the question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The state you are looking for is the `focus` state

There are actually 4 states in the GIF you presented

1. Normal (light pink)
2. Hover (darker pink, mouse is hovering)
3. Active (when you are still holding on, but dragging away)
4. Focus (not pink anymore but still focused with blue rectangle)

Cannot replicate your gif exactly, but here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alexyu/1bvsv53k/) demonstrating these 4 states.

Comment: Provide some CSS examples to show the 4 states in action, e.g. `button:active { ... }` etc. — maybe even to exactly mimic the gif — and your answer would be much better.

Comment: @StephenP Just added a fiddle for clearer demonstration, no idea how to make gifs :)

Comment: @gitsitgo Thanks, nice answer! You could probably take that JSFiddle and add it as a [Snippet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to the answer itself if you wanted to